# how to bind column value from database to html dropdownlist in mvc4 using ado.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to bind column value of database to dropdownlist using storedprocedure in mvc4
i dont know how to handle this .plz help me

my model code is like this

```
 public class dropdown
{
    string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnstr"].ConnectionString;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "DomainName is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "DomainName")]
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dropdown> obj { get; set; }

    public List<dropdown> LoadDomain(dropdown model)
    {
        List<dropdown> obj = new List<dropdown>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectDomainName", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    var data = new dropdown();
                    data.DomainName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DomainName"].ToString();
                    obj.Add(data);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        return obj;
```

in `obj` i am getting all the column values

my controller code

```
 public ActionResult binddropdown(dropdown model1)
    {

            var x = model1.LoadDomain(model1);

            ViewData. = x;

            return View(model1);

    }
```

i dont know wheather i am going in direction or not. i am a beginner so plz suggest me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set your data in viewbag and then on front side you can loop through data and assign value to your dropdownbox. here what you can do is,

```
public ActionResult binddropdown(dropdown model1)
{
        var x = model1.LoadDomain(model1);
        viewbag.MyData = x;
        return View();
}
```

and on front end side you can fetch data from viewbag (conver to appropriate type using typecast if required) and can assign to html tag like   like this,

```
   @{
 var a = (yourobjtypecast) viewbag.MyData ;
<select name="drpId" id="drpId">
      <option value="yourvalue"> Select </option>

                @foreach (var te in a)
                {
                    <option value='@te.ID.ToString()'>@te.Nam </option>

                }
 </select>
}
```

I hope this work.

Comment: a is just a variable defined above on first line where we have taken our data from viewbag dear. you have to use        @{   //coding part   }  this anotation to work with code on front end along with html

Comment: in my dropdownlist i am not getting data

Comment: have yo debug ? are you geting data on var "a" ? can you post your code here ? set debug point near var "a" and then check is data coming or not